# Visual C# .NET Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement and ; Expected

Tags: c#, mysql

So I get these 2 errors:
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.
; Expected

On a code I made for a button, to save new info into the database (MySQL) This is the full button code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //create new account button
    {
        if ((textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("First name is not filled.", "Houston, we have a problem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        if ((textBox2.Text.Trim().Length == 0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Last name is not filled.", "Houston, we have a problem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        if ((textBox3.Text.Trim().Length == 0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insert your current cash in hand.", "Houston, we have a problem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        if ((textBox4.Text.Trim().Length == 0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insert your new Credit Card Number.", "Houston, we have a problem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        if ((textBox4.Text.Trim().Length < 16 || textBox4.Text.Trim().Length > 16))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Credit card length has to contain 16 digits.", "Houston, we have a problem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else {
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=botmaker";
            string Query = "insert into database.user (firstName,lastName,handCash,cardNumber)  values('"+this.textBox1.Text+"','"+this.textBox2.Text+"','"+this.textBox3.Text"','"+this.textBox4.Text+"') ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                    MessageBox.Show("New bank account created! Thank you for joining 'BARm's Bank Inc.' Your new plan will start soon", "Welcome to our bank!");
                    //this.Close();
                while(myReader.Read()){


                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Houston, we have a problem");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the line that I get the error from:

```
string Query = "insert into database.user (firstName,lastName,handCash,cardNumber)  values('"+this.textBox1.Text+"','"+this.textBox2.Text+"','"+this.textBox3.Text"','"+this.textBox4.Text+"') ;";
```

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're missing a `+` here: `this.textBox3.Text"','"+`. And please consider using a parameterized query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a mistake in your query part (You missed a `+`):

```
 +this.textBox3.Text"','"+this.text
```

Should be

```
 +this.textBox3.Text + "','"+this.text
```

Comment: I feel so stupid, thanks a lot! (I went over the code hundreds of times...lol)